# How to get information from database to a div or form field in angular js?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

I am want my all information to be print on the form field or in any elements in angularjs . i have tried but still didnt show. i am making crud application when user click on edit button then form should pop up with its information.
my form is

```
<form  ng-controller="TablesPageCtrl">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="title" name="title">

</div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label >Description</label>
      <!-- <input type="text" ng-model ="description" name="description" -->
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" ng-model ="form.description" name="description" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label >Duration</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "form.duration" name="duration" placeholder="Enter Title">
    </div>


    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update"></input>
  </form>
```

and mycontroller is

```
function TablesPageCtrl($scope, $filter, editableOptions, editableThemes, $window, $http, $uibModal, baProgressModal) {


  //it is called from edit button which i didnt display on html code  $scope.open = function(page, size,id,title) {
      $scope.m = 'hello';
      $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: page,
        size: size,
        resolve: {
          items: function() {
            return $scope.items;
          }
        }
      });
      $http.get("api/get-course/" + id).then(function(res) {
        console.log(res.data.response.data);
        $scope.lists = res.data.response.data;
        var k  = res.data.response.data.title;
        alert(k);
        $scope.test = { k};
        // alert($scope.test)
      });
      // $scope.newObject = [{'items': id}];
      // // form.title = id;

      //
      // console.log(id);
    };
    $scope.openProgressDialog = baProgressModal.open;

    editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
    editableThemes['bs3'].submitTpl = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-with-icon"><i class="ion-checkmark-round"></i></button>';
    editableThemes['bs3'].cancelTpl = '<button type="button" ng-click="$form.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default btn-with-icon"><i class="ion-close-round"></i></button>';
```

}

Comment: check the res argument from your http.get, to see in wich format came and then equals to your $scope.title.

Comment: i have tried all thie things but stil it didnt work

Comment: can you share al your controller.js , maybe the function where is the $http arent called

Comment: what iam seen is when you call your $http you asing to $scope.lists, but in the view, i dont see how to bind it, for debuggin, try to put <pre>{{lists | json}}</pre> and look if it have the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$scope.title = res.data.title;
```

If that doesn't work, try console logging out just `res` and looking at the format the data was returned in.